# What is maxThreadPoolSize at ActiveMQConnection

Tags: activemq-classic

When I configure `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` for a producer I found there is a config for `maxThreadPoolSize`.

```java
@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setMaxThreadPoolSize();
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

What does this mean? Any usage at producer part? Or it is used for consumer connection threadpool?

Answer (score 2):

That is a setting for the internal ActiveMQConnection to use for processing async tasks on the Session.

The default is 1000. 99% of users should never need to adjust it.